# How to connect to RDS using local subnet even when the PostgreSQL RDS is exposed to the internet to avoid latency

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have a Rails app on Heroku which uses an exposed PostgreSQL RDS publicly on AWS.

I also have an EC2 instance on AWS which connects to the same PostgreSQL RDS, but I'm using the same public endpoint to connect to the database, and I'd like to connect locally using a subnet.

Both DB and EC2 instance is in the same subnet, but I don't know the endpoint to connect locally instead of using the public endpoint and connecting using the internet.

Could you guys help me, please? I want to connect to my db locally to avoid latency.

I've been googling and checking the docs for it, and I didn't find a solution or why it can't be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the RDS endpoint for RDS access from within your VPC and DNS will resolve to the instance's private IPv4 address.

> We resolve a public DNS hostname to the public IPv4 address of the
>   instance outside the network of the instance, and to the private IPv4
>   address of the instance from within the network of the instance.

See [Using DNS with Your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html).

Comment: It's true, I used `dig database-hostname` from both the EC2 instance and my local machine and the IP was different. Thank you very much.